# Problem when using generator-rn-toolbox to apply icon and splash screen

Tags: react-native, icons

I want to use generator-rn-toolbox to set icon and splash screen for my react-native app but it always shows

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
>           throw err;
>       Error: Cannot find module 'universal-analytics'*

then I install 'universal-analytics', but nothing changes, there is always an error.

Comment: Hey Zita, I'm a contributor of  generator-rn-toolbox, can you open an issue on the repository with the step to reproduce it please?

Comment: Hi Pierre, is this what you ask for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458678/problem-when-using-generator-rn-toolbox-to-apply-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package manager here.

As stated in [the Github issue](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/issues/240) I just released a fix.
I made a rookie mistake of forgetting to commit a package.json change.
Sorry for the inconvenience